# Error with including docker container name and id in json logs

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Im trying to make some containers output the name and ID as part of the log string. I saw in Docker documentation you can modify that output so modified the logging part of the docker compose yml file as shown below, but im getting the following error saying

> ERROR: Cannot create container for service init: unknown log opt 'tag'
> for json-file log driver

I also tried adding the tag option outside of the options: level and got a similar error. Am i doing this wrong?

```
logging:
    driver: "json-file"
    options:
        tag: "{{.Name}}/{{.ID}}"
        max-size: "25m"
        max-file: "2"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like either (a) an error in your `docker-compose.yaml`, or possibly (b) you're using a version of Docker that doesn't support custom log tags (I'm not sure when this support was introduced).

With Docker 20.10.16 (and docker-compose 1.28.6), I can successfully start the following `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
version: "3"

services:
  logtest:
    image: docker.io/alpine:latest
    command:
      - sh
      - -c
      - |
        while true; do
          date
          sleep 5
        done
    logging:
      driver: json-file
      options:
        tag: "{{.Name}}/{{.ID}}"
```

Looking at the underlying container logs, I see log lines like:

```
{"log":"Tue Jun  7 19:33:11 UTC 2022\n","stream":"stdout","attrs":{"tag":"work_logtest_1/1625fe35f408"},"time":"2022-06-07T19:33:11.071303972Z"}
```

So we see that (a) the container started without errors and (b) the `tag` option is being interpreted correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the info, we are hosting docker in a RHEL server, version info shows 1.13.1. I know they do weird backports of docker, so im thinking this is an issue with redhats implementation maybe not supporting this feature.

Comment: It looks likerecent versions of Docker can be [installed on RHEL 7 and 8](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/rhel/).